# how would I sort a list and get the top K elements? (STL)

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of doubles. I want to sort it from highest to lowest, and get the indices of the top K elements. std::sort just sorts in place, and does not return the indices I believe. What would be a quick way to get the top K indices of largest elements?

Comment: Wouldn't they be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9?

Comment: After sorting, the first K elements (or last K elements) would be the top elements.

Comment: after sort, yes, but apparently kop would like to find the indices in the original range, before the sort.

Comment: that's what the OP is getting at -- kop doesn't want to sort them in place.

Comment: @Martin: that need not be true. The vector might by construction have same order as some other data, somewhere else. The original index therefore tells you which element in that other data corresponds to each of the top K double values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is somewhat hackish, but you could define a struct that stored both the double and its original index, then overload the < operator to sort based on the double:

```
struct s {
    double d;
    int index;
    bool operator < (const struct &s) const {
        return d < s.d;
    }
};
```

Then you could retrieve the original indices from the struct.

Fuller example:

```
vector<double> orig;
vector<s> v;
...
for (int i=0; i < orig.size(); ++i) {
    s s_temp;
    s_temp.d = orig[i];
    s_temp.index = i;
    v.push_back(s);
}
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
//now just retrieve v[i].index
```

This will leave them sorted from smallest to largest, but you could overload the > operator instead and then pass in greater to the sort function if wanted.

Comment: nth_element as you suggested wouldn't work if the top N needed to be sorted themselves; partial_sort would only be significantly quicker if K was pretty small and n rather large -- n log(K) as opposed to n log(n); but feel free to use partial_sort instead if you need the performance, but you'll have to overload the > operator and sort from biggest to smallest then (partial_sort sorts the top part of the elements, not the bottom part)

Comment: Yes, you're right. But when you don't have any expectations about K and N (don't know how much K will be smaller than N), it's better to use partial sort (I think) - it could be faster in 50% of the cases, but it's still a less-time-lost. And just one remark - you don't need to overload operator> to do the oposite and make it seem complicated, if you need. You could just pass a function, defined by you, to partial_sort. For example: `partial_sort( myvector.begin(), myvector.begin() + 5, myvector.end(), myfunction );` It's similar with nth_element, too.

Answer (score 16):

you could use the [`nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) STL algorithm - this will return you the N greatest elements ( this is the fastest way,using stl ) and then use .sort on them,or you could use the partial_sort algorithm,if you want the first K elements to be sorted (:

Using just .sort is awful - it is **very** slow for the purpose you want.. .sort is great STL algorithm,but for sorting the whole container,not just the first K elements (; it's not an accident the existung of nth_element and partial_sort ;)

Comment: +1 for finding nth_element. (please link to official docs though)

Comment: http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element , there you can find the partial_sort, too

Comment: I guess I meant "formal" rather than "official". Look at SGI or HP (the former is online, the latter since Stepanov was working at HP when STL came out)

Comment: Would the usage be like the following? `vector< double > dblVec; nth_element( &dblVec[ 0 ], &dblVec[ K ], &dblVec[ 0 ] + dblVec.size() ); ` The result is in `dblVec[ 0 ]` to `dblLvec[ K - 1 ]`.

Comment: using default comparison (operator <): `nth_element( myvector.begin(), myvector.begin() + 666, myvector.end() );`
 Using function for comparing: `nth_element( myvector.begin(), myvector.begin() + 666, myvector.end(), myfunction );`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about pre-canned algorithms, but take a look at [selection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements); if you need the top K elements of a set of N values and N is much larger than K, there are much more efficient methods.

If you can create an indexing class (like @user470379's answer -- basically a class that encapsulates a pointer/index to the "real" data which is read-only), then use a priority queue of maximum size K, and add each unsorted element to the priority queue, popping off the bottom-most element when the queue reaches size K+1. In cases like N = 10<sup>6</sup>, K = 100, this handles cases much more simply + efficiently than a full sort.

Answer (score 0):

OK, how about this?

```
bool isSmaller (std::pair<double, int> x, std::pair<double, int> y)
{
   return x.first< y.first;
}

int main()
{
   //...
   //you have your vector<double> here, say name is d;
   std::vector<std::pair<double, int> > newVec(d.size());
   for(int i = 0; i < newVec.size(); ++i)
   {
      newVec[i].first = d[i];
      newVec[i].second = i;  //store the initial index
   }
   std::sort(newVec.begin(), newVec.end(), &isSmaller);
   //now you can iterate through first k elements and the second components will be the initial indices
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `multimap` for `vector`'s (value, index) to handle dups.  Use reverse iterators to walk results in descending order.

```
#include <multimap>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

multimap<double, size_t> indices;
vector<double> values;

values.push_back(1.0);
values.push_back(2.0);
values.push_back(3.0);
values.push_back(4.0);

size_t i = 0;
for(vector<double>::const_iterator iter = values.begin(); 
        iter != values.end(); ++iter, ++i)
{
    indices.insert(make_pair<double,int>(*iter, i));
}

i = 0;
size_t limit = 2;
for (multimap<double, size_t>::const_reverse_iterator iter = indices.rbegin(); 
    iter != indices.rend() && i < limit; ++iter, ++i)
{
    cout << "Value " << iter->first << " index " << iter->second << endl;
}
```

Output is

> Value 4 index 3
>
> Value 3 index 2

If you just want the `vector` indices after sort, use this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<double> values;

values.push_back(1.0);
values.push_back(2.0);
values.push_back(3.0);
values.push_back(4.0);

sort(values.rbegin(), values.rend());
```

The top K entries are indexed by 0 to K-1, and appear in descending order. This uses reverse iterators combined with standard `sort` (using `less<double>` to achieve descending order when iterated forward. Equivalently:

```
sort(values.rbegin(), values.rend(), less<double>());
```

Sample code for the excellent `nth_element` solution suggested by @Kiril here (K = 125000, N = 500000).  I wanted to try this out, so here it is.

```
vector<double> values;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
{
    values.push_back(rand());
}

nth_element(values.begin(), values.begin()+375000, values.end());
sort(values.begin()+375000, values.end());

vector<double> results(values.rbegin(), values.rbegin() + values.size() - 375000);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you actually need a structure that maps indices to corresponding doubles.

You could use `std::multimap` class to perform this mapping. As Jason have noted `std::map` does not allow duplicate keys.

```
std::vector<double> v; // assume it is populated already
std::multimap<double, int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    m.insert(std::make_pair(v[i], i));
...
```

After you've done this you could iterate over first ten elements as map preserves sorting of keys to the elements.